# Area of scanned (2D) figure

Tags: image, photoshop, pixel, area, scanning

Lets say I have 100 one-colored A4 sheets of paper, that are cut into different shapes and figures (2D), scanned, saved as an image file, and then needs to be sorted in ascending order of area.

Is there an effective way to find the area of the figures and arrange them?

Answer (score 1):

If all pictures have the same size and all shapes the same color (that´s the situation if I don´t missunderstand your question), you can calculate the average color value.

The nearer the calculated color comes to the figures´s color, the bigger is the shape on the Image.

Some code:

```
private Color GetAverageImageColor(Image img)
    {
        double[] rgb = new double[3];
        Color col;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img);

        for(int y = 0; y < bmp.Size.Height; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < bmp.Size.Width; x++)
            {
                col = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                rgb[0] += col.R;
                rgb[1] += col.G;
                rgb[2] += col.B;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            rgb[i] /= (bmp.Size.Height * bmp.Size.Width);
            rgb[i] = Math.Round(rgb[i]);
        }

        return Color.FromArgb((int) rgb[0], (int) rgb[1], (int) rgb[2]);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, all 100 sheets of paper are of the same size and color; seems you've understood the situation perfectly.

I think your solution might work, thank you! This kind of short-cut-solution was exactly what I was looking for - priority number 1 is getting the ordering right in an effective way; finding an accurate value for the area is secondary (but would be great as well).

I will report back as soon as I've had the chance to try your solution (probably some time during the weekend).